# Adding textbox to modal popup stopped allowing INSERTS

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox

I have a modal popup that allows an admin to choose from a variety of checkboxes to add features to a specific product. If there is a checkbox that an admin believes should be available but isn't because that feature is not in the database, I have added a textbox so that user can add a new feature to the product.

Once I added the textbox, it stopped allowing inserts. At first it was in the same If Else as the checkbox for each loop, but I have recently changed it so the textbox is in it's own for each loop. I have an underline under the words txtFeature.Text that says `Value of type 'Char' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.UI.WebControl.Textbox.'`

vb code:

```
  For Each feature As ListItem In cbxAddFeature.Items
        If feature.Selected Then

            Dim strSQL As String = "INSERT INTO Marketing 
                                   (ProductID, MarketingTypeID, MarketingTitle,
                                    MarketingData) 
                                    VALUES (@ProductID, 3, 'Feature', @MarketingData);
                                    UPDATE Product SET ModifyDate = getdate(), 
                                    ModifyUser = @ModifyUser 
                                    WHERE ProductID = @ProductID"

            Using cn As New SqlConnection
            (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
            ("LocalSqlServer").ConnectionString)

                Using cmd As New SqlCommand(strSQL, cn)

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ProductID", ProductID.Value))
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@MarketingData", 
                    feature.Value))
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ModifyUser", 
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name))

                    cn.Open()

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using

                cn.Close()
            End Using
        Else
        End If
    Next
    For Each txtFeature As TextBox In txtFeature.Text
        If txtFeature.Text Then
            Dim featureSql As String = "INSERT INTO Marketing(ProductID, 
                                        MarketingTypeID, MarketingTitle, MarketingData) 
                                        VALUES (@ProductID, 3, 'Feature', 
                                        @MarketingData);
                                        UPDATE Product SET ModifyDate = getdate(), 
                                        ModifyUser = @ModifyUser 
                                        WHERE ProductID = @ProductID; 
                                        INSERT INTO Feature (FeatureTitle) 
                                        VALUES (@FeatureTitle)"

            Using cn As New SqlConnection
            (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
            ("LocalSqlServer").ConnectionString)

                Using cmd As New SqlCommand(featureSql, cn)

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@FeatureTitle", 
                                       txtFeature.Text))

                    cn.Open()

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using

                cn.Close()
            End Using
        End If
```

aspx:

```
<div class="PopupHeader">Add a Feature</div>
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbxAddFeature" runat="server" 
             DataSourceID="dsNewFeatures" DataTextField="FeatureTitle" 
             DataValueField="FeatureID"></asp:CheckBoxList>
            New Feature:<asp:TextBox ID="txtFeature" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Label ID="FeatureError" runat="server" ></asp:Label><br />
             <asp:Button ID="SubmitFeatures" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
             <asp:Button ID="CancelSubmitFeatures" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="FeatureModal" runat="server" 
         BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="CancelSubmitFeatures" 
         DropShadow="True" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" 
         PopupControlID="FeaturePanel" TargetControlID="FeatureButton"> 
        </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Comment: It sounds like you should be tackling the problem of CheckBoxes not showing up when they should be. A problem with a work-around usually means to revisit the drawing board and getting to the source of the problem.

Comment: The checkboxes aren't the problem at all. The modal popup worked perfectly before I added the textbox. The textbox is the problem. Sorry if I didn't clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to iterate over a string and cast each character in it to TextBox class: `For Each txtFeature As TextBox In txtFeature.Text`. Obviously you got an error. Just remove that cycle and check `txtFeature.Text` property instead: `If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFeature.Text) Then ...`